# TeamCity anaconda error: Unsatisfiable dependencies for platform win-64

Tags: python, anaconda, teamcity, conda-build

I am trying to build (conda-build) and test (pytest) my python project with help of anaconda and TeamCity.

TeamCity is working fine for Linux, but for Windows I have an error on the testing build step (Linux and Windows use the same `meta.yaml` file):

```
    failed to get install actions, retrying: exception was: 
Unsatisfiable dependencies for platform win-64: {'urlib3==1.26.11=pyhd8ed1ab_0', ... <GIANT LIST OF LIBRARIES>
```

Important to say that the first step (build packages with help of conda-build) is working
But the second step (test step) is failing with the error above. So i think that the error deals with `pytest` related libs.

```
**meta.yaml**

    {% set version = "1.1.0" %}
    
    package:
      name: myname
      version: {{ version }}
    
    source:
      path .. 
    build:
      number: 0
      skip: True
      pin_depends: strict
    
    requirements:
      build:
        - python >= 3.8,<3.9
      run:
        - pythonv>=3.8,<3.9
        - docker-py
        - holidays
        - scipy
        - requests >=2.23.0
        - numpy <1.22.0
        - matplotlib >= 3.5.0,<4.0
        ...
        - requests-negotiate-sspi # [win]

    test:
      requires:
        - pytest
        - pytest-asyncio
        - pytest-cov
        - pytz
        - coverage
        - dateutils
        - pytest-xdist
        - pytest-benchmark
        - teamcity-messages
        - pytest-bdd
    source_files:
        - conftest.py
    comands:
        - pytest <PATH_TO_FILE>
```

TeamCity test step looks like this:

```
conda-build <MY_PATH>\win_64\*.tar.bz2 <MY CHANNELS> --override-channels --test
```